# Multiple filter in the file selection window in vbscript

Tags: filter, vbscript

I have a file selection window. It's fine. Becouse  I can't show all files, so     I used filter. I want to view only txt and xml files and filter is OK., but I need to view both types of files **simultaneously**. Now when window is opening only txt files are show and to show xml files I have to change filter every time. How can I make filter with "OR"? Somebody can help me?
My code:

```
On Error Resume Next
'--- choose file ---------------
Function GetFileDlgEx(sIniDir,sFilter,sTitle) 
 Set oDlg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<object id=d classid=clsid:3050f4e1-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b></object><script>moveTo(0,-9999);eval(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0).Read("&Len(sIniDir)+Len(sFilter)+Len(sTitle)+41&"));function window.onload(){var p=/[^\0]*/;new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(p.exec(d.object.openfiledlg(iniDir,null,filter,title)));close();}</script><hta:application showintaskbar=no />""") 
 oDlg.StdIn.Write "var iniDir='" & sIniDir & "';var filter='" & sFilter & "';var title='" & sTitle & "';" 
 GetFileDlgEx = oDlg.StdOut.ReadAll 
 End Function

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
sFilter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|XML files(*.xml)|*.xml||" 
sTitle = "You can select your file" 
MyFile = GetFileDlgEx(Replace(sIniDir,"\","\\"),sFilter,sTitle) 

Set objFile = FSO.GetFile(MyFile)
sName = objFile.Name
sPath = objFile.Path
sPath = Left(sPath, Len(sPath)-Len(sName))

f.Close
fso.Close

If MyFile = "" Then
  msgbox "File not selected"
  WScript.Quit
End if
vchoose = sPath & sName 
msgbox vchoose
```

Comment: _The first string in each pair is a display string that describes the filter (for example, "Text Files"), and the second string specifies the filter pattern (for example, ".TXT"). To specify multiple filter patterns for a single display string, use a semicolon to separate the patterns (for example, ".TXT;.DOC;.BAK"). A pattern string can be a combination of valid file name characters and the asterisk (*) wildcard character. Do not include spaces in the pattern string._ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea

Comment: Thanks Mark!
This is it what I need. I tried to use the separator, but I used a comma and it didn't work. Unfortunately, I was do it at 1 am and  I was so tired. Small thing, but enjoys. Thanks again.